# Visual Studio Code - Node.js - Cannot find name '__dirname'

Tags: node.js, macos, visual-studio-code

Just to preface I'm not a professional coder, but nonetheless I got roped into building a website for my boss after he found out I took "Web Design" in high school 10 years ago.  Back then static sites were fine, and heck CSS was just starting to show it's potential, but I digress.

I'm working on a Node.js project on Visual Studio Code right now and have a weird exception.  The code works fine, but I guess it's just curiosity at this point.  Anyway, here's my code.

app.js

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
multer = require('multer'),
controller = require('./controllers');

//Sets the view engine to jade.
app.set('views', __dirname + '/frontend');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

//sets up the development enviroment
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.locals.pretty = true;
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/build/public'))
  var build = require(__dirname + '/build.js');
  app.use('css/*', function(req, res, next){
    build.style();
    next();
  });
}

//Sets up the public directory to serve static files - This will be depricated quite soon...
//app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

//Initalizes site-wide local variables
//app.set('title', 'Halvorson Homes');

//Sets up body-parser to be able to read RESTful requests
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(multer({dest: 'tmp'}).fields());

//Load Controllers
app.use( '/' , controller);


//makes the app listen on port 3000
app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port 3000...');
})
```

My folder structure is pretty much as follows

- controllers

  - index.js
  - designs.js
- models

  - designs.js
- frontend

  - common

    - layout.jade
    - header.jade
    - footer.jade
    - client.js
    - style.less
  - index

    - index.jade
    - client.js
    - style.less
  - designs

    - index.jade
    - client.js
    - style.less
- build

  - tmp
  - srv
- app.js
- build.js
- package.json

According to VS Code's built in debugger there's exceptions on lines 8, 14, and 15. They're the only places I used __dirname in the entire project.  This is an annoying to me, as I am too much of a perfectionist.  Is it Node, VS Code, or something else?

Comment: Please provide your folder structure. Did you install typings and created jsconfig? Check the following link for detailed info how to setup a project.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The warning you are getting is from the [eslint extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint). While it may be valid in Node.JS, it's warning you about `__dirname` because it's not valid in all JavaScript environments such as in browsers.

To suppress the warning you will want to create an `.eslintrc` file in your project's root directly and indicate that the code will be running in node like so:

```
{
    "env": {
        "node": true
    }
}
```

You can see the `.eslint` file used to configure eslint for the actual vscode codebase here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/.eslintrc.json

Answer (score 8):

Late to the party, but just had the same issue. The fix for me was to add the node types so VSCode recognises them:

Go to the Terminal view, then enter the following:
`npm install @types/node --save-dev`

Then hit `Cmd + Shift + P` (for Mac at least) to bring up the VSCode command search dialogue, then select `Reload Window`.

When it reappears, that error and any other related to Node.JS stuff not being recognised should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to creating a separate `.eslintrc` file, you can also add it to the `package.json` file.

The [docs](https://eslint.org/docs/6.0.0/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments) state:

> To specify environments in a configuration file, use the env key and specify which environments you want to enable by setting each to true. For example, the following enables the browser and Node.js environments

```
{
    "name": "mypackage",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "eslintConfig": {
        "env": {
            "browser": true,
            "node": true
        }
    }
}
```